# Main class not found / available?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package com.mycompany.example;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

class Fruits {
    String name;
    double price;
    char quality;
    
    Fruits() {
        // Parameterless constructor
    }
    
    Fruits(String name, double price, char quality) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quality = quality;
    }
    
    Fruits(Fruits fruit) {
        this.name = fruit.name;
        this.price = fruit.price;
        this.quality = fruit.quality;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + ", Price: " + price + ", Quality: " + quality;
    }
}

class Dehydrated extends Fruits {
    int quantity;
    boolean inTray;
    
    Dehydrated() {
        // Parameterless constructor
    }
    
    Dehydrated(String name, double price, char quality, int quantity, boolean inTray) {
        super(name, price, quality);
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.inTray = inTray;
    }
    
    Dehydrated(Dehydrated dehydrated) {
        super(dehydrated);
        this.quantity = dehydrated.quantity;
        this.inTray = dehydrated.inTray;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", Quantity: " + quantity + ", In Tray: " + inTray;
    }
    
    void state() {
        if (inTray) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter quality: ");
            quality = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("State is only available for fruits in the tray.");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating arrays for each class
        Fruits[] fruitsArray = new Fruits[3];
        Dehydrated[] dehydratedArray = new Dehydrated[3];
        
        // Instantiating objects for the Fruits class using the three constructors
        fruitsArray[0] = new Fruits();
        fruitsArray[1] = new Fruits("Oranges", 4.5, 'B');
        fruitsArray[2] = new Fruits(fruitsArray[1]);
        
        // Instantiating objects for the Dehydrated class using the three constructors
        dehydratedArray[0] = new Dehydrated();
        dehydratedArray[1] = new Dehydrated("Apricots", 7.2, 'A', 20, true);
        dehydratedArray[2] = new Dehydrated(dehydratedArray[1]);
        
        // Calling the state() method for some instances of the Dehydrated class
        dehydratedArray[1].state(); // Will read from keyboard and modify
        dehydratedArray[2].state(); // Will not modify
        
        // Writing the modified instance results to a text file
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("results.txt");
            for (Dehydrated dehydrated : dehydratedArray) {
                writer.write(describeChanges(dehydrated));
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // Testing the created methods
        testMethods(fruitsArray, dehydratedArray);
    }
    
    // Method that describes changes for an instance of Dehydrated
    private static String describeChanges(Dehydrated dehydrated) {
        if (dehydrated.inTray) {
            return "Name: " + dehydrated.name + ", Quality: " + dehydrated.quality + "\n";
        } else {
            return ""; // If not in tray, no changes are made
        }
    }
    
    // Method for testing the created methods
    private static void testMethods(Fruits[] fruitsArray, Dehydrated[] dehydratedArray) {
        // Testing display methods
        for (Fruits fruit : fruitsArray) {
            System.out.println(fruit);
        }
        for (Dehydrated dehydrated : dehydratedArray) {
            System.out.println(dehydrated);
        }
        
        // Testing the state() method
        for (Dehydrated dehydrated : dehydratedArray) {
            dehydrated.state();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm encountering an issue with NetBeans where it's unable to find my Main class. I've set up my project in NetBeans, but when I try to run it, I'm getting an error indicating that the Main class cannot be found. I've checked the project configuration and ensured that the Main class is present in the correct package and has the correct main method signature. Despite this, NetBeans still can't locate it when I attempt to run the program. I'm seeking assistance in troubleshooting this issue and resolving why NetBeans is unable to locate my Main class during execution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you done a search to see if this or a similar problem has been asked and answered before?  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bnetbeans%5D+main+class+not+found

Comment: Questions of this type should include an exact copy of the error message. Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class that contains the startup `main()` method is the proper one selected within the NetBeans project properties. In the Projects tab on the left IDE panel, right-click on the project title you are working on and from the popup menu, select the **Properties** menu item.

The **Projeccy Properties** dialog window will display. Again, in the left pane, select the **Run** item. Now in the right pane of the Project Properties dialog you can see a caption titled **Main Class:**. Make sure the text within the field contains the package and class name of where your startup `main()` method is located. If not, then select the <kbd>Browse...</kbd> button next to the field and select the proper class from the **Browse Main Classes** dialog that pops up and then select the <kbd>Select Main Class</kbd> button. Now select the <kbd>OK</kbd> button located at the bottom of the **Project Properties** dialog window.

Now select **Run** from the NetBeans menu bar and then select the **Clean & Build Project** menu item. Check the **Output** pane for any errors during the clean and build. Resolve any issues indicated in red text and try again if necessary. If the clean & build is fine (no errors) then try to run your project.